# Yii2 Restful API - Example to Add a New Action

Tags: api, rest, yii2

For buiding restful API using Yii2, does anyone has good example on how to add a new action in a controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am not sure if you are asking for extra actions beside CRUD or just for CRUD, so I write in details for both cases.

Firstly, the framework includes `\yii\rest\ActiveController` that provides typical restful API operation and URL management.

Basically, the controller predefines the CRUD operations as followed:

`POST /resource` -> `actionCreate` -> Create the resource

`GET /resource/{id}` -> `actionView` -> Read the resource

`PUT, PATCH /resource/{id}` -> `actionUpdate` -> Update the resource

`DELETE /resource/{id}` -> `actionDelete` -> Delete the resource

`GET /resource` -> `actionIndex` -> List all the resources

The URL routing rules and actions definition can be found in `\yii\rest\ActiveController`, `\yii\rest\UrlRule` and the respective `\yii\rest\*Action`.

Secondly, if you want to add extra restful API in the controller, you can simply write your extra `actionXxxxx()`, and in configuration, add the following url rules under `urlManager`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => ['resource'],
            'pluralize' => false,
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'POST {id}/your_preferred_url' => 'xxxxx', // 'xxxxx' refers to 'actionXxxxx'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Effectively, this will generate a new routing rule, requesting `POST /resource/{id}/your_preferred_url` will invoke `actionXxxxx` of your ResourceController.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Little note though: this extra pattern will be for every controller specified, but you can add another rule with other controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good example using **Yii 2 advanced application template**

https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api

more detail of this project http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

also you can use **Yii 2 basic application template** if you want.
what you have to do is follow this kind of folder structure (v1 for version) [(Yii doc -A module may consist of sub-modules.)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html)[(GiovanniDerks - backend sub-modules)](http://www.slideshare.net/GiovanniDerks/yii-backend-submodules-28238101)

```
-modules
--api
---v1
----controllers
----models
```