# how to add add extra action in yii2 rest api?

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I have a problem with yii2 rest. I follow http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/ to begin.
Now, I want add new extra action to countrycontroller that return "Hello World". I have add extraPatterns to my api config according to this two links ;

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701247/yii2-restful-api-example-to-add-a-new-action and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query`

I can't comment there to ask this problem.

When I want test HelloWorld action, there is problem "404 : Object not found".
Would anyone likes to explain me about how should I config my new action?

Comment: please be more specific what you have as code. espacially in your config and the part of the controller

Comment: actually i've got the answer of my question. I just only add new rule of my new controller..Tks before,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26031015/1278748

Comment: I have the same problem and I found out this answer, hope it help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701247/yii2-restful-api-example-to-add-a-new-action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701247/yii2-restful-api-example-to-add-a-new-action)