# Yii Override Generic Rest Functions

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am new to yii2. I want to write restful api in yii framework. From 3 days of searching I am able to run restful services example. I found that yii generates these methods automatically index, view, create, update, delete. What will I do if I want to customize index, create, update and delete method? Because I have only found method to customize output of index function which is prepareDataProvider. And what will I do if I add new method? Or is it better to write your own custom methods if yii not provide customization of create, update and delete method.

Answer (score 7):

You can always override the original behavior by defining the `actions()` method in your `ActiveController` class.

Here is an example:

```
 public function actions()
 {
     return array_merge(parent::actions(), [
         'create' => null, // Disable create
         'view' => [
             'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
             'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
             'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
             'findModel' => ['\path\to\your\callback', 'findModelByYourOwnMethod'],
         ],
         'update' => [
             'class' => 'path\to\your\UpdateAction',
             'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
             'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
             'scenario' => SCENARIO_UPDATE,
         ],
     ]);
 }
```

You can define your own action class, scenario, etc. If you want to override some but not all actions, remember to merge with `parent::actions()`.

**EDIT**

In general, you can always add extra actions in the controller by 1) declaring method `actionX()`, where X is the name of action; and/or 2) declaring method `actions()` which returns array of action configuration, just like the example above. And `Yii2` framework provides a special controller `\yii\rest\ActiveController` which provides implemented actions for CRUD and index.

If you read the source code, you will notice that in `ActiveController`, there is `actions()` method which defined something similar to the example above. Each *action* has linked to a `class` under the same package, for example, `'index' => ['class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction']`. Implementation in every action is different, and some of them provides an optional *callable* variable for developer to set and override original behavior. `IndexAction`, for example, provides `$prepareDataProvider;` for you to override; and you can see from my example, `$findModel` is another one that appears in every *rest* action.

I am not going to put the list of such *callable* variable here unless there are strong needs from the community. To understand what is needed to fill in in order to extend the *rest action* behavior, please check the source code under `rest` folder of the framework: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework/rest ; and FYI, I have another answer which may help you understand more: [Yii2 Restful API - Example to Add a New Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701247/yii2-restful-api-example-to-add-a-new-action/26031015#26031015)

Comment: I can't understand how can I change functionality of create or update method? While index function gives me prepareDataProvider to customize its functionality. What should be my configuration for create or update method? And Where should I write my code?

Comment: @RowanTaylor, see edited, and I have updated the example, you can change the `class` that points to your own implemented action class

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I feel this question is very similar to one I've answered. It would be worthwhile to check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744982/3337682

Hope it helps someone.

~ Cheers :)