# Yii2 REST ful Api how to send status code

Tags: rest, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

[Yii2 Restful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701247/yii2-restful-api-example-to-add-a-new-action)

In the above link they mention for GET Search method , Please anyone tell me for like POST create and PUT Update ...

In `main.config` under rules i created like,

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'v1/lkup-access-profile','extraPatterns' => ['POST create' => 'create']],
```

But its comes error as Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.

Answer (score 0):

yii\rest\UrlRule will create default REST URLs and actions. There's no need to add 'extraPatterns' => ['POST create' => 'create']. It's already built in. Check out the docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html

Use extraPatterns to extend default routes for controller. For example

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'v1/invite',
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'PUT {id}/accept' => 'accept',
        'PUT {id}/reject' => 'reject',
    ],
],
```